# How to highlight result of a search in Flask/HTML?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I m trying to create a search box Using HTML and Flask framework from Python.
I have the following layout :
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slh4g.png)

I want to take the input of the search box and highlight it in the text zone ! I want to perform a search in the same HTML page !

For example if I type : "544" the last line will be highlighted.

I m filling the box automatically with content of a list : Python script :

```
@app.route('/update_loc_debug', methods=['POST'])
def update_loc_debug():

loc_debug = ''
if loc_debug_msg not in loc_list:
    loc_list.append(loc_debug_msg)
for i in range(len(loc_list)):
    loc_debug= loc_debug + "\n" + loc_list[i]

return jsonify('', render_template('update_loc_debug.html', loc_debug=loc_debug))
```

This is the part responsible of filling the box in HTML :

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script>
$(function(){
    window.setInterval(function(){
        loadNewLocDebug()
    },3000)
function loadNewLocDebug(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/update_loc_debug",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $(loc_debug).replaceWith(data)
        }
    });
}
});
</script>

<div  class="loc-debug-title">
    Loc Debug UART
</div>

<div id="loc_debug" class="textzone3">
    {{ loc_debug }}
```

Can you please suggest any possible solution ? or documentation.
Do I have to use a search form or I can perform the search using live data.

Thanks!

Comment: Colouring should be done in frontend because you are calling backend through Ajax.

Comment: I m calling backend using Ajax, and some new text in added every 3s! so the text zone is dynamically updated ! I want to be able to color all text similar to what is typed in the search box!

Answer (score 0):

Your textzone looks like a textarea. If you don't need users to edit the contents of the textzone, then you don't actually need a textarea. You can simply use a list element `<ul>` with each text coming in as a list item `<li>` which means you can style the `<li>` for the most recent entry differently e.g. maybe give it a class called 'active' and then style  it how you want

Comment: It's like a text area but it's updated dynamically every 3s ! so it's not constant ! I want to be able to color all texts that matches with what I type in the search box !